# Magento 2.3 - eWay payment gateway Decoding failed: Syntax error

Tags: payment-gateway, magento2.3.4

How to solve the error **Decoding failed: Syntax error**

I am using this eWay magento extension : https://marketplace.magento.com/eway-eway-rapid-magento2.html

If click place order page redirect to cart and return error **Decoding failed: Syntax error**

Answer (score 0):

Try to download eway Payment Method using CLI. in Marketplace you will not get full source.Even you download eWay Payment Method then you have to download base library using CLI.

Comment: Now i installed using composer, anything else i need to do further?

Comment: You can get whole extension using library, while you download eway extension. You can get commands from eway website. and also you can get latest version from it. Once i got this type of issue and i had discussed with eway technical support, that guy told me to download eway from CLI.

Comment: have you got your solution? or try to download and configure eway using below commands.
composer require eway/eway-rapid-magento2 3.0.2 -- 3.0.2 --> version which you want to download

composer update

php bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content Eway_DirectConnection Eway_SharedPage Eway_SecureFields Eway_IFrame Eway_TransparentRedirect Eway_EwayRapid

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Instead of install by using composer is any other way exits?

Comment: May i know what PHP version support Eway 3.0.2 version app, my php version :  7.3.21

Comment: Actually previously, I faced an issue in eWay, So that time i had discussed with Technical support team, they told me to download and setup eWay extension using composer. So from then I used only command Line for download and setup eway. and for php version support you have to discuss with eway support team only.

Comment: Hello arpit2011, any help with this issue, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/319888/57334