# Magento 2.3 - How to solve Multi-Site Eway Payment page Mysql error

Tags: checkout, database, payment, magento2.3.4

How to solve the following error,

[image]

Network Error :

> trace: "#0
> /var/www/html/test/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(9400,
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment),
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))↵#1
> /var/www/html/test/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callParent('savePaymentInfo...',
> Array)↵#2
> /var/www/html/test/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(9400,
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment),
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))↵#3
> /var/www/html/test/generated/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/PaymentInformationManagement/Interceptor.php(26):
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins('savePaymentInfo...',
> Array, Array)↵#4 [internal function]:
> Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement\Interceptor->savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder(9400,
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Payment),
> Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address))↵#5
> /var/www/html/test/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(95):
> call_user_func_array(Array, Array)↵#6
> /var/www/html/test/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest.php(188):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process(Object(Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request\Proxy))↵#7
> /var/www/html/test/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))↵#8
> /var/www/html/test/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
> Array)↵#9
> /var/www/html/test/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))↵#10
> /var/www/html/test/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(26):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch',
> Array, Array)↵#11
> /var/www/html/test/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(116):
> Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))↵#12
> /var/www/html/test/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(261):
> Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()↵#13
> /var/www/html/test/pub/index.php(44):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))↵#14
> {main}"

Comment: Print value first from this line case 'longtext': $value = (string)$value; if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') { $value = null; } break;.

Comment: try to restart your server and check

Comment: @MohitPatel Yes, i did, still issue.

Comment: hi, can you provide the link for module download so we can analyze it?

Comment: @RiccardoUgolini Extension : https://marketplace.magento.com/eway-eway-rapid-magento2.html Installed by composer

Comment: @zus do you have done any customization on it?

Comment: @RiccardoUgolini No, Just use the extension as it is

Comment: are you using Community Magneto 2.3.4 and you face the above issue when just select this one, right?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Exactly

Comment: magento version and module version? @zus  write the complete version please

Comment: @RiccardoUgolini Magento version 2.3.4 and module https://marketplace.magento.com/eway-eway-rapid-magento2.html Anything pls let me know

Comment: @RiccardoUgolini FYI Amount received in Payment Gateway, success page redirect issue log => https://justpaste.it/8qla2

Comment: @zus , what is your PHP version?

Comment: @ChiragRajput  PHP Version => 7.3.21

Comment: @ChiragRajput Any help, i am trying almost everything, still facing the issue?

Comment: @zus , the screenshot said that it have issue in checkout and you are saying in above comment that Amount received in Payment Gateway. SO can you explain exact issue where you are getting above error?

Comment: If the customer enter credit card details, then submit, the same page getting an error, https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXuCf.png

Comment: May I know which Magento version you are using and which PHP version you are using?

Comment: PHP version => 7.3.x

Comment: Magento Version?

Comment: Magento Version 2.3.4

Comment: eway extension ver: 3.0.5

Comment: How to solve this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXuCf.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve this issue make the changes below paths.

**Path** : `vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`

**Look For** --> `public function prepareColumnValue(array $column, $value)`

> **Replace below old code:**

```
case 'longtext':
    $value  = (string)$value;
    if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
        $value = null;
    }
 break;
```

> **With new code:**

```
case 'longtext':
    if(!is_array($value)) $value  = (string)$value;
    else $value = '';
    if ($column['NULLABLE'] && $value == '') {
        $value = null;
    }
   break;
```

Let me know if this one resolve your issue.

Comment: Is it recommend to do changes in core files?

Comment: In my vendor/magento there is no framework folder, how to reach Mysql.php file?

Comment: @zus, Which Magento 2 version you are currently using?

Comment: My Magento version  2.3.4

Comment: Your solution working for, my major doubt is right what we did, Is it recommend to do changes in core files?

Comment: @zus, for testing purpose, do these changes in core if it's worked then add in your changelog and you have to take care only  Magento version update time otherwise it is fine. If the answer is helpful please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to downgrade your PHP version from PHP7.3 to PHP7.1.x

Magento 2.3.4 is compatible with PHP7.1.x

Comment: Could you pls recommend PHP 7.2.x series? what series of 7.2.x support eway extension? We build some application based on 7.2.x series

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#php  PHP 7.1 announced EOL

Comment: I am using 7.2.33-1 in UBUNTU-20.04. Try with this.